# Sorting a collection of objects

Tags: java, sorting, collections

If I have a simple list of Strings:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I can sort it with:

```
Collections.sort(stringList);
```

But suppose I have a Person class:

```
public class Person
{
   private String name;
   private Integer age;
   private String country;
}
```

And a list of it:

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

And I want to sort it sometimes by name, sometimes by age, sometimes by country.

What is the easiest way to accomplish that?

I know that I can implement the Comparable interface, but that seems to limit me to sort it by one specific property.

Comment: maybe you shouldn't use the adjective "composite" in the title, as it sounds like the Composite Pattern...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Implement the [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface (once for each different sort order) and use the [Collections.sort()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) method that takes a Comparator as additional parameter.

Answer (score 52):

Collections.sort can be called with a custom comparator. And that comparator can be implemented to allow sorting in different sort orders. Here's an example (for your Person model - with age as an Integer):

```
public class FlexiblePersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
  public enum Order {Name, Age, Country}

  private Order sortingBy = Name;

  @Override
  public int compare(Person person1, Person person2) {
    switch(sortingBy) {
      case Name: return person1.name.compareTo(person2.name);
      case Age: return person1.age.compareTo(person2.age);
      case Country: return person1.country.compareTo(person2.country);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Practically unreachable code, can't be thrown");
  }

  public void setSortingBy(Order sortBy) {
    this.sortingBy = sortingBy;
  }
}
```

And you use it like that (assuming persons is a field):

```
public void sortPersonsBy(FlexiblePersonComparator.Order sortingBy) {
  List<Person> persons = this.persons;  // useless line, just for clarification
  FlexiblePersonComparator comparator = new FlexiblePersonComparator();
  comparator.setSortingBy(sortingBy);
  Collections.sort(persons, comparator); // now we have a sorted list
}
```

Comment: +1 I like the idea of a flexible comparator

Comment: You could also pass the sortingBy parameter in a constructor.

Comment: [Answer by @Yishai in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421322/how-do-i-sort-a-list-with-multiple-sort-parameters#1421537) demonstrates elegant use of enum for custom sorting and grouped  sorting (multiple arguments) utilizing comparator chaining.

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Answer (score 17):

Thanks to the responders. For the benefit of others, I'd like to include a complete example.

The solution is the create the following additional classes:

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Person>
{
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2)
    {
       return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
   }
}

public class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Person>
{
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2)
    {
        return o1.getAge().compareTo(o2.getAge());
    }
}

public class CountryComparator implements Comparator<Person>
{
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2)
    {
        return o1.getCountry().compareTo(o2.getCountry());
    }
}
```

The list can then be sorted like this:

```
Collections.sort(personList, new NameComparator());
Collections.sort(personList, new AgeComparator());
Collections.sort(personList, new CountryComparator());
```

Answer (score 12):

The Java 8 way of doing this is to use [`List.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) as follows:

```
personList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName));
```

To quote [Stuart Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441122/stuart-marks) in his answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25962666/276052).

> This is the big advantage of the `List.sort(cmp)` extension method over `Collections.sort(list, cmp)`. It might seem that this is merely a small syntactic advantage being able to write `myList.sort(cmp)` instead of `Collections.sort(myList, cmp)`. The difference is that `myList.sort(cmp)`, being an interface extension method, *can be overridden* by the specific `List` implementation. For example, `ArrayList.sort(cmp)` sorts the list in-place using `Arrays.sort()` whereas the default implementation implements the old copyout-sort-copyback technique.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the [BeanComparator](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/commons-beanutils-1.6.1/docs/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html) from apache commons beanutils, like this:

```
Collections.sort(personList, new BeanComparator("name"));
```

Comment: Nice one. Not seen that before

Answer (score 4):

Implement 3 different types of Comparator.

you can add the comparator to the sort command. The comparator you define, will sort the elements by name, age, or what ever.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {

        public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
            if (!(arg0 instanceof Person)) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (!(arg1 instanceof Person)) {
                return -1;
            }

            Person pers0 = (Person)arg0;
            Person pers1 = (Person)arg1;


            // COMPARE NOW WHAT YOU WANT
            // Thanks to Steve Kuo for your comment!
            return pers0.getAge() - pers1.getAge();
        }
    });
```

Comment: why not using parametric type for Comparator?

Comment: because i am coming from 1.4 ;)

Comment: You could just return pers0.getAge() - pers1.getAge(). That will work for a three cases (<, > and ==).

Answer (score 2):

The Collections.sort method can be invoked with a second argument which is the comparator to use.
Create 3 comparators and use the one you want when appropriate.

```
Collections.sort(list , new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
          ...
        }
      });
```

Comment: awwww ... Comparator<Person> ... syntatic sugar is tasty!

Comment: yup, i think too so. it should be `Collections.sort(Person , new Comparator<Person>() {`

Answer (score 1):

Using lambdaj ( http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/ ) you can achieve what you're asking in the following way:

sort(personList, on(Person.class).getName());

sort(personList, on(Person.class).getAge());

sort(personList, on(Person.class).getCountry());

Answer (score 0):

I asked a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134339/) (about searching rather than sorting), perhaps there is some useful information (I ended up using an `enum` that implements `Comparator` so I pass the `enum` value as a comparator selector).