# How to sort List of objects by some property

Tags: java, sorting, sort-object

I have simple class

```
public class ActiveAlarm {
    public long timeStarted;
    public long timeEnded;
    private String name = "";
    private String description = "";
    private String event;
    private boolean live = false;
}
```

and `List<ActiveAlarm>` con. How to sort in ascending order by `timeStarted`, then by `timeEnded`? Can anybody help? I know in C++ with generic algorithm and overload operator <, but I am new to Java.

Comment: [Answer by @Yishai in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421322/how-do-i-sort-a-list-with-multiple-sort-parameters#1421537) demonstrates elegant use of enum for custom sorting and grouped  sorting (multiple arguments) utilizing comparator chaining.

Answer (score 159):

Using [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html)

**For Example:**

```
class Score {

    private String name;
    private List<Integer> scores;
    // +accessor methods
}
```

---

```
    Collections.sort(scores, new Comparator<Score>() {

        public int compare(Score o1, Score o2) {
            // compare two instance of `Score` and return `int` as result.
            return o2.getScores().get(0).compareTo(o1.getScores().get(0));
        }
    });
```

With Java 8 onwards, you can simply use lambda expression to represent Comparator instance.

```
Collections.sort(scores, (s1, s2) -> { /* compute and return int */ });
```

Comment: What does `compareTo()` do? Where does it come from? Where do I have to define it?

Comment: @Asqiir `getScores()` is the getter for `scores` which is a `List<Integer>`. When you do `getScores().get(0)` you get an `Integer` object. `Integer` already has the `compareTo(anotherInteger)` method implemented, you don't have to define it.

Comment: what is get(0)?

Comment: Thanks works like a charm (I use it without the .get(0) part). How could I reverse the order?

Comment: Return the ordered objects list? or modify same list object?

Answer (score 153):

Either make `ActiveAlarm` implement `Comparable<ActiveAlarm>` or implement `Comparator<ActiveAlarm>` in a separate class. Then call:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

or

```
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

In general, it's a good idea to implement [`Comparable<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) if there's a single "natural" sort order... otherwise (if you *happen* to want to sort in a particular order, but might equally easily want a different one) it's better to implement [`Comparator<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). This particular situation could go either way, to be honest... but I'd *probably* stick with the more flexible [`Comparator<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) option.

EDIT: Sample implementation:

```
public class AlarmByTimesComparer implements Comparator<ActiveAlarm> {
  @Override
  public int compare(ActiveAlarm x, ActiveAlarm y) {
    // TODO: Handle null x or y values
    int startComparison = compare(x.timeStarted, y.timeStarted);
    return startComparison != 0 ? startComparison
                                : compare(x.timeEnded, y.timeEnded);
  }

  // I don't know why this isn't in Long...
  private static int compare(long a, long b) {
    return a < b ? -1
         : a > b ? 1
         : 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: That compare() function isn't in Long likely because the implementation is even more trivial: return a - b;

Comment: @papercrane: No, that fails for overflow reasons. Consider `a = Long.MIN_VALUE, b = 1`.

Comment: as of API 19 (KitKat) Long now has a `.compare`

Answer (score 85):

**JAVA 8 and Above Answer (Using Lambda Expressions)**

In Java 8, Lambda expressions were introduced to make this even easier!  Instead of creating a Comparator() object with all of it's scaffolding, you can simplify it as follows: (Using your object as an example)

```
Collections.sort(list, (ActiveAlarm a1, ActiveAlarm a2) -> a1.timeStarted-a2.timeStarted);
```

or even shorter:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(ActiveAlarm ::getterMethod));
```

That one statement is equivalent to the following:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ActiveAlarm>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ActiveAlarm a1, ActiveAlarm a2) {
        return a1.timeStarted - a2.timeStarted;
    }
});
```

Think of Lambda expressions as only requiring you to put in the relevant parts of the code:  the method signature and what gets returned.

Another part of your question was how to compare against multiple fields.  To do that with Lambda expressions, you can use the `.thenComparing()` function to effectively combine two comparisons into one:

```
Collections.sort(list, (ActiveAlarm a1, ActiveAlarm a2) -> a1.timeStarted-a2.timeStarted             
       .thenComparing ((ActiveAlarm a1, ActiveAlarm a2) -> a1.timeEnded-a2.timeEnded)
);
```

The above code will sort the list first by `timeStarted`, and then by `timeEnded` (for those records that have the same `timeStarted`).

One last note: It is easy to compare 'long' or 'int' primitives, you can just subtract one from the other.  If you are comparing objects ('Long' or 'String'), I suggest you use their built-in comparison.  Example:

```
Collections.sort(list, (ActiveAlarm a1, ActiveAlarm a2) -> a1.name.compareTo(a2.name) );
```

EDIT:  Thanks to Lukas Eder for pointing me to `.thenComparing()` function.

Comment: You might appreciate the new Java 8 API `Comparator.comparing().thenComparing()`...

Comment: Watch out with returning difference. In case of overflow, you can get wrong result.

Comment: This is IMHO the easier sorting method, again  assuming you don't have an obvious natural order.  You also don't need to call `Collections` anymore, you can call directly onto the list.  For example: `myList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Address::getZipCode).thenComparing(Compartor.comparing(Address::getStreetName));`

Comment: or even shorter use:- list.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(ActiveAlarm ::getterMethod));

Answer (score 21):

**We can sort the list in one of two ways:**

**1. Using Comparator** : When required to use the sort logic in multiple places
If you want to use the sorting logic in a single place, then you can write an anonymous inner class as follows, or else extract the comparator and use it in multiple places

```
  Collections.sort(arrayList, new Comparator<ActiveAlarm>() {
        public int compare(ActiveAlarm o1, ActiveAlarm o2) {
            //Sorts by 'TimeStarted' property
            return o1.getTimeStarted()<o2.getTimeStarted()?-1:o1.getTimeStarted()>o2.getTimeStarted()?1:doSecodaryOrderSort(o1,o2);
        }

        //If 'TimeStarted' property is equal sorts by 'TimeEnded' property
        public int doSecodaryOrderSort(ActiveAlarm o1,ActiveAlarm o2) {
            return o1.getTimeEnded()<o2.getTimeEnded()?-1:o1.getTimeEnded()>o2.getTimeEnded()?1:0;
        }
    });
```

We can have null check for the properties, if we could have used 'Long' instead of 'long'.

**2. Using Comparable(natural ordering)**: If sort algorithm always stick to one property:
write a class that implements 'Comparable' and override 'compareTo' method as defined below

```
class ActiveAlarm implements Comparable<ActiveAlarm>{

public long timeStarted;
public long timeEnded;
private String name = "";
private String description = "";
private String event;
private boolean live = false;

public ActiveAlarm(long timeStarted,long timeEnded) {
    this.timeStarted=timeStarted;
    this.timeEnded=timeEnded;
}

public long getTimeStarted() {
    return timeStarted;
}

public long getTimeEnded() {
    return timeEnded;
}

public int compareTo(ActiveAlarm o) {
    return timeStarted<o.getTimeStarted()?-1:timeStarted>o.getTimeStarted()?1:doSecodaryOrderSort(o);
}

public int doSecodaryOrderSort(ActiveAlarm o) {
    return timeEnded<o.getTimeEnded()?-1:timeEnded>o.getTimeEnded()?1:0;
}
```

}

call sort method to sort based on natural ordering

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 16):

In java8+ this can be written in single line as follows:

`collectionObjec.sort(comparator_lamda)` or `comparator.comparing(CollectionType::getterOfProperty)`

code:

```
ListOfActiveAlarmObj.sort((a,b->a.getTimeStarted().compareTo(b.getTimeStarted())))
```

or

```
ListOfActiveAlarmObj.sort(Comparator.comparing(ActiveAlarm::getTimeStarted))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public class ActiveAlarm implements Comparable<ActiveAlarm> {
    public long timeStarted;
    public long timeEnded;
    private String name = "";
    private String description = "";
    private String event;
    private boolean live = false;

    public int compareTo(ActiveAlarm a) {
        if ( this.timeStarted > a.timeStarted )
            return 1;
        else if ( this.timeStarted < a.timeStarted )
            return -1;
        else {
             if ( this.timeEnded > a.timeEnded )
                 return 1;
             else
                 return -1;
        }
 }
```

That should give you a rough idea. Once that's done, you can call `Collections.sort()` on the list.

Answer (score 5):

Since Java8 this can be done even cleaner using a combination of [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [`Lambda expressions`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

**For Example:**

```
class Student{

    private String name;
    private List<Score> scores;

    // +accessor methods
}

class Score {

    private int grade;
    // +accessor methods
}
```

---

```
    Collections.sort(student.getScores(), Comparator.comparing(Score::getGrade);
```

Answer (score 4):

### Java-8 solution using [Stream API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html):

**A.** When `timeStarted` and `timeEnded` are `public` (as mentioned in the requirement) and therefore do not (need to) have `public` getter methods:

```
List<ActiveAlarm> sorted = 
    list.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong((ActiveAlarm alarm) -> alarm.timeStarted)
                        .thenComparingLong((ActiveAlarm alarm) -> alarm.timeEnded))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**B.** When `timeStarted` and `timeEnded` have `public` getter methods:

```
List<ActiveAlarm> sorted = 
    list.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(ActiveAlarm::getTimeStarted)
                        .thenComparingLong(ActiveAlarm::getTimeEnded))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### If you want to sort the original `list` itself:

**A.** When `timeStarted` and `timeEnded` are `public` (as mentioned in the requirement) and therefore do not (need to) have `public` getter methods:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingLong((ActiveAlarm alarm) -> alarm.timeStarted)
                    .thenComparingLong((ActiveAlarm alarm) -> alarm.timeEnded));
```

**B.** When `timeStarted` and `timeEnded` have `public` getter methods:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(ActiveAlarm::getTimeStarted)
                    .thenComparingLong(ActiveAlarm::getTimeEnded));
```

Answer (score 3):

Guava's [ComparisonChain](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ActiveAlarm>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(ActiveAlarm a1, ActiveAlarm a2) {
                 return ComparisonChain.start()
                       .compare(a1.timestarted, a2.timestarted)
                       //...
                       .compare(a1.timeEnded, a1.timeEnded).result();
            }});
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `Comparator.comparing()` method to sort a list based on an object's property.

```
class SortTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ActiveAlarm> activeAlarms = new ArrayList<>(){{
            add(new ActiveAlarm("Alarm 1", 5, 10));
            add(new ActiveAlarm("Alarm 2", 2, 12));
            add(new ActiveAlarm("Alarm 3", 0, 8));
        }};

        /* I sort the arraylist here using the getter methods */
        activeAlarms.sort(Comparator.comparing(ActiveAlarm::getTimeStarted)
                .thenComparing(ActiveAlarm::getTimeEnded));

        System.out.println(activeAlarms);
    }
}
```

Note that before doing it, you'll have to define at least the getter methods of the properties you want to base your sort on.

```
public class ActiveAlarm {
    public long timeStarted;
    public long timeEnded;
    private String name = "";
    private String description = "";
    private String event;
    private boolean live = false;

    public ActiveAlarm(String name, long timeStarted, long timeEnded) {
        this.name = name;
        this.timeStarted = timeStarted;
        this.timeEnded = timeEnded;
    }

    public long getTimeStarted() {
        return timeStarted;
    }

    public long getTimeEnded() {
        return timeEnded;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Alarm 3, Alarm 2, Alarm 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Employee POJO Class

```
package in.ac.adit.oop.sort;

public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String department;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    public Employee(int id, String name, String department) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", department=" + department + "]";
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
}
```

Employee Class To Manage Employee

```
package in.ac.adit.oop.sort;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class Example {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            /*
             * Create 10 Employee Object
             */
            Employee emp1 = new Employee(1, "Nayan", "IT");
            Employee emp2 = new Employee(2, "Siddarth", "CP");
            Employee emp3 = new Employee(3, "Samarth", "AE");
            Employee emp4 = new Employee(4, "Bhavesh", "CV");
            Employee emp5 = new Employee(5, "Sam", "FT");
            Employee emp6 = new Employee(6, "Keyur", "IT");
            Employee emp7 = new Employee(7, "Bala", "ME");
            Employee emp8 = new Employee(8, "Mitul", "ME");
            Employee emp9 = new Employee(9, "Kamlesh", "EE");
            Employee emp10 = new Employee(10, "Piyush", "EE");
    
            /*
             * List of Employee Object
             */
            List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
            employeeList.add(emp1);
            employeeList.add(emp2);
            employeeList.add(emp3);
            employeeList.add(emp4);
            employeeList.add(emp5);
            employeeList.add(emp6);
            employeeList.add(emp7);
            employeeList.add(emp8);
            employeeList.add(emp9);
            employeeList.add(emp10);
    
            CustomObjectSort customObjectSort = new CustomObjectSort();
            List<Employee> sortByDepartment = customObjectSort.sortByDepartment(employeeList);
    
            /*
             * Sorted By Department
             */
            for (Employee employee : sortByDepartment) {
                System.out.println(employee);
            }
    
            /*
             * Sorted By Name
             */
            List<Employee> sortByName = customObjectSort.sortByName(employeeList);
    
            for (Employee employee : sortByName) {
                System.out.println(employee);
            }
    
            /*
             * Sorted By Id
             */
            List<Employee> sortById = customObjectSort.sortById(employeeList);
    
            for (Employee employee : sortById) {
                System.out.println(employee);
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Custom Sorting

```
package in.ac.adit.oop.sort;


import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomObjectSort {

    public List<Employee> sortByName(List<Employee> employeeList) {

        Collections.sort(employeeList, new Comparator<Employee>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Employee employee1, Employee employee2) {
                return employee1.getName().compareTo(employee2.getName());
            }

        });
        return employeeList;
    }

    public List<Employee> sortByDepartment(List<Employee> employeeList) {

        Collections.sort(employeeList, new Comparator<Employee>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Employee employee1, Employee employee2) {
                return employee1.getDepartment().compareTo(employee2.getDepartment());
            }

        });
        return employeeList;
    }

    public List<Employee> sortById(List<Employee> employeeList) {

        Collections.sort(employeeList, new Comparator<Employee>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Employee employee1, Employee employee2) {
                return employee1.getId() - employee2.getId();
            }

        });
        return employeeList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what did the trick for me.
Was much shorter and easier than everything else I found:

```
Collections.sort(listName, Comparator.comparing(Object::getProperty).reversed());
```

The ".reversed()" part at the end was a requirement for my specific project but I'm sharing it too, as it took a while to find it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Collections.sort`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and pass your own [`Comparator<ActiveAlarm>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Answer (score 1):

In java you need to use the static `Collections.sort` method. Here is an example for a list of CompanyRole objects, sorted first by begin and then by end. You can easily adapt for your own object.

```
private static void order(List<TextComponent> roles) {

    Collections.sort(roles, new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            int x1 = ((CompanyRole) o1).getBegin();
            int x2 = ((CompanyRole) o2).getBegin();

            if (x1 != x2) {
                return x1 - x2;
            } else {
                int y1 = ((CompanyRole) o1).getEnd();
                int y2 = ((CompanyRole) o2).getEnd();
                return y2 - y1;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call Collections.sort() and pass in a Comparator which you need to write to compare different properties of the object.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can sort by:

- Making your object implement `Comparable`
- Or pass a `Comparator` to `Collections.sort`

If you do both, the `Comparable` will be ignored and `Comparator` will be used. This helps that the value objects has their own  logical  `Comparable` which is most reasonable sort for your value object, while each individual use case has its own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```html
public class ActiveAlarm {
    public long timeStarted;
    public long timeEnded;
    private String name = "";
    private String description = "";
    private String event;
    private boolean live = false;
}

List<ActiveAlarm> con = new ArrayList<ActiveAlarm>();

Collections.sort(con , (a1, a2) -> a1.timeStarted.compareTo(a2.timeStarted));
Collections.sort(con , (a1, a2) -> a1.timeEnded.compareTo(a2.timeEnded));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The best and the easiest way to sort any list of objects in Java (Java 8 and above).
Lets sort a basket of fruits based on the property "fruitName"

Fruit POJO:

```
class Fruit
{
    int price;
    String fruitName;
    
    
    public Fruit(int price, String fruitName) {
        super();
        this.price = price;
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
    }


    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }


    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }


    public String getFruitName() {
        return fruitName;
    }


    public void setFruitName(String fruitName) {
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fruits [price=" + price + ", fruitName=" + fruitName + "]";
    }
    
}
```

Now lets add fruits into a list and then sort it

```
List<Fruit> basketOfFruits = new ArrayList<>();
        basketOfFruits.add(new Fruit(123, "oranges"));
        basketOfFruits.add(new Fruit(45, "nectarine"));
        basketOfFruits.add(new Fruit(369, "blueberries"));
        basketOfFruits.add(new Fruit(248, "apple"));
        basketOfFruits.add(new Fruit(968, "peaches"));
        basketOfFruits.add(new Fruit(436, "grapes"));
        basketOfFruits.add(new Fruit(596, "figs"));
        
       //sorting by the property fruitName
        Collections.sort(basketOfFruits, (f1, f2)->{return f1.getFruitName().compareTo(f2.getFruitName());});
```

You can now print the list (i.e basketOfFruits) and the fruits in the list would be sorted in ASCENDING order (lexicographically).
The output would look like this:

```
[Fruits [price=248, fruitName=apple], Fruits [price=369, fruitName=blueberries], Fruits [price=596, fruitName=figs], Fruits [price=436, fruitName=grapes], Fruits [price=45, fruitName=nectarine], Fruits [price=123, fruitName=oranges], Fruits [price=968, fruitName=peaches]]
```

Instead of Collections.sort(), Java streams can also be used (Java 8 and above). The following is the code using Java streams

```
List<Fruit> sortedFruits = basketOfFruits.stream().sorted( (f1, f2)->{return f1.getFruitName().compareTo(f2.getFruitName());}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

here the list is sorted in the same manner as Collections.sort(), but the sorted items would be stored/collected in another list "sortedFruits". So, if we want to print the sorted items of the list, we need to print "sortedFruits" instead of "basketOfFruits" in this case

Comment: This question has been answered already a dozen times in a similar fashion as your answer. Please don't add answers that do not improve the existing answers.