# Kotlin, recyclerview adapter how to sort results from query by DESC

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

its my code. What i doing wrong? I would like to display descending results in recyclerview.

```
TableInfo.TABLE_COLUMN_MESSAGE = "points"

override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: MojViewHolder, p1: Int) {

    val wynikwynik = p0.view.textViewWynik
    val wynikuser = p0.view.textView_user


    val cursor = db.query(TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, BaseColumns._ID + "=?", arrayOf(p0.adapterPosition.plus(1).toString()), null, null, TableInfo.TABLE_COLUMN_MESSAGE +" DESC")



    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){

        wynikwynik.text=cursor.getString(1).toString()
        wynikuser.text=cursor.getString(2).toString()

    }


    cursor.close()

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort RecyclerView item in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790363/how-to-sort-recyclerview-item-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should separate the view of your Business Logic, I want to say you shouldn't do a db request within of recyclerView, the best way is pass an val of data in your recyclerView, this data is the info for your recyclerView lList, if you make a db request inside of your ViewHolder you are making a request in every row of your List and this is a problem.

Check this information of the work of a recycler view:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

This statement fetches only 1 row, because as I understand `BaseColumns._ID` is the primary key of the table. 
So you pass `p0.adapterPosition.plus(1).toString()` as an argument to the statement and the `query()` method fetches the row with this id. 
So **there is no sorting for only 1 row**!  
If you want to fetch all the rows of the table sorted descending, you must execute this statement:

```
val cursor = db.query(TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, TableInfo.TABLE_COLUMN_MESSAGE + " DESC")
```

or even better use `rawQuery()`:

```
val cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableInfo.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + TableInfo.TABLE_COLUMN_MESSAGE + " DESC", null)
```

Answer (score 0):

hard-coding sort-order `DESC` prevents any alternate (remote or database) sorting ...

at least unless the adapter items not implement `Comparable<T>` (for local sorting).

to query the database `onBindViewHolder()` is just wrong.