# sort list of object on java 8 with custom criteria

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I have a list of `MyObject`

```
List<MyObject> myObjects;
```

where `MyObject` is a model class something like below

```
public class MyObject{

private String fName;
private String lname;
private String code;

//getter setter

}
```

there are four possible value of code let's say `ABC,DEF,XYZ and PQR`.

Now i want to sort the list based on following criteria. All object with code value `XYZ` should come first, followed by `PQR`,`ABC` and `DEF`.

1. XYZ
2. PQR
3. ABC
4. DEF

I want to achieve this using java 8 if possible. How can i sort my ArrayList.

Comment: Use a custom `Comparator`. [How to sort List of objects by some property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805602/how-to-sort-list-of-objects-by-some-property) would be a good place to start

Comment: i figured that part but was not achieve to make it work.

Comment: If you want help, you must show what you tried.

Comment: `myObjects.sort((o1, o2) -> {
            if(o1.getCode().equals("XYZ"))
                return -1;
            else if(o2.getCode().equals("XYZ"))
                return 1;
           // <do the same for all codes in the order you want>
            else
                return o1.getCode().compareTo(o2.getCode());
        });`

Comment: Remember, you're comparing the keys of two objects and how the relate to each other

Comment: assign a numeric value to each code: XYZ -> 1, PQR -> 2, ABC -> 3, DEF -> 4. Get the numeric value for o1, and the one for o2. Compare the numeric values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are only four possible values that your code variable can take, you could save them in a map and compare the values when sorting your list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {             
    List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    myObjects.add(new MyObject("fName1", "lname1", "ABC"));
    myObjects.add(new MyObject("fName2", "lname2", "PQR"));
    myObjects.add(new MyObject("fName3", "lname3", "XYZ"));
    myObjects.add(new MyObject("fName4", "lname4", "DEF"));

    Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("XYZ", 1);
    map.put("PQR", 2);
    map.put("ABC", 3);
    map.put("DEF", 4);

    Comparator<MyObject> sortByCode = (obj1,obj2)->Integer.compare(map.get(obj1.code), map.get(obj2.code));
    System.out.println("Before sorting");
    System.out.println(myObjects);

    System.out.println("After sorting");
    myObjects.sort(sortByCode);
    System.out.println(myObjects);
}
```

Comment: Can it done on original list and not create another list ?

Comment: @user9735824 I have updated my code to sort your original list without creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to create your own `Comparator` for comparing instances of `MyObject` according to your logic:

```
Comparator<MyObject> cmp = (o1, o2) ->{
    //Implement comparison logic here
    //Compare o1 and o2 and return -1,0, or 1 depending on your logic
};
```

Then given a list such as this:

```
List<MyObject> listToSort = ...
```

You can either sort it in-place using the old `Collections.sort()` function:

```
Collections.sort(listToSort, cmp);
```

Or, if you want, using Java 8 streams:

```
listToSort.stream().sorted(cmp).collect(Collectors.toList()); //Using streams
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the main problem i am having is actually Implementing  comparison logic