# Sort a list by another list

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a little problem that is driving me crazy.

I have a

- `List<Integer>` with ids.
- `List<ObjectA>` with 3 variables:
  an id, and two string

I have to sort the second list by putting at the top the elements with id contained in the first list, then by string asc and by the second string asc.

What is the easiest way to make this work? I am trying to use the .sort(), Comparators etc.

An example:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ObjectA {
      private Integer id;
      private String code;
      private String name;
}

// comparator:
    static class SortByCode implements Comparator<ObjectA> {
        public int compare(ObjectA a, ObjectA b) {
            String as = a.getCode();
            String bs = b.getCode();

            return as.compareTo(bs);
        }
    }
    static class SortByName implements Comparator<ObjectA> {
        public int compare(ObjectA a, ObjectA b) {
            String as = a.getName();
            String bs = b.getName();

            return as.compareTo(bs);
        }
    }

// then in service:  
List<Integer> idsPreferred = new ArrayList<>();
List<ObjectA> listObj = new ArrayList<>();

idsPreferred = .... add preferred ids;
listObj = .... add objects;  
listObj.sort(new SortByCode()).thenComparing(new SortByName());
```

With this i sort by code and by name - but i need to add the sorting by the first list - I need the elements that have an id contained in the List to come before the others.

Comment: can you post the code using comparator??

Comment: Can you add an example please?

Comment: I have added a more in-depth explanation and an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose something like this using chained comparing by extracted key:

```
listObj.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> !idsPreferred.contains(((ObjectA) o).getId()))
                       .thenComparing(o -> ((ObjectA) o).getId())
                       .thenComparing(o -> ((ObjectA) o).getCode())
                       .thenComparing(o -> ((ObjectA) o).getName()));
```

or

```
listObj.sort(Comparator.comparing(ObjectA::getId,
                                  (id1,id2)-> {if (!((idsPreferred.contains(id1))^idsPreferred.contains(id2)))
                                                  return 0;
                                               else return (idsPreferred.contains(id2))?1:-1;})
                       .thenComparing(ObjectA::getId)
                       .thenComparing(ObjectA::getCode)
                       .thenComparing(ObjectA::getName));
```

Comment: it is very good and satisfies my request, thank you. but can you tell me why the cast is needed?

Comment: @Ed-Genesis Really I can'not explain this. But I've posted second solution.

Answer (score -1):

The solution will involve 2 steps-

1. check id of objects from second list, which are present in first list.
2. Sort the contained objects using either of the solutions suggested- [How to sort List of objects by some property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805602/how-to-sort-list-of-objects-by-some-property)