# Most efficient way to sort 2 arrays but considering just one of them in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

(Sort students) Write a program that prompts the user to enter the number of stu-dents, the students’ names, and their scores, and prints student names in decreas-ing order of their scores.

So I just solved this problem, but I think is a more efficient way to do so. For instance, I created 2 methods with one array each to create Scores and student´s names then another method to sort only the scores array but also in the same method, I created a new array to save the index of each value so it would match with the student´s names array when I printed in the main. Overall, there must be an easier way to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I would consider creating a `Grade` class that has a `student` and a `score` field, and then you could sort a `List<Grade>` by comparing each `grade.score`

Comment: or you can do `Grade[] students = new Grade[numberOfStudents];`

Answer (score 2):

## Define a class

You asked:

> Overall, there must be an easier way to solve this problem.

Yes, there is… don't use separate arrays to track related data (generally).

If you are tracking a score for each student, you should be defining a class to represent that data. Java is an object-oriented language, so make use of objects!

### `record`

Java 16 brings a new briefer way to define a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably: [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

You merely need to define the type and names of the member fields.

```java
public record Scoring ( String studentName , int score ) {}
```

For a record, the compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

Collect instances of your class in a `List` or `Set`.

```java
int initialCapacity = 3 ;  // Specify how many elements do you expect to use.
List< Scoring > scorings = new ArrayList<>( initialCapacity ) ;
scorings.add( new Scoring( "Alice" , 98 ) ) ;
scorings.add( new Scoring( "Bob" , 88 ) ) ;
scorings.add( new Scoring( "Carol" , 77 ) ) ;
```

Or your classwork may be focused on using arrays rather than [Java Collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework).

```java
Scoring[] scorings = new Scoring[ 3 ] ;
scorings[ 0 ] = new Scoring( "Alice" , 98 ) ;
…
```

As for gathering input from the user via the console, [search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20scanner&t=osx&ia=web) to see many existing Questions and Answers on using `Scanner` class.

As for sorting a collection of objects by one of the properties of that class, search Stack Overflow to see many existing Questions and Answers using [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)) while passing an implementation of [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html). Such as [*How to sort List of objects by some property*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5805602/642706), [*How do I sort a list by different parameters at different timed*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1421322/642706), and [*How to sort an arraylist of objects by a property?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535124/642706).