# Implement sorting by propertyX then by propertyY then by propertyZ in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

Given a the following class:

```
class Boo {
    private final String propertyX;
    private final Double propertyY;
    private final Integer propertyZ;
}
```

How would one go about constructing a `Comparator` which would result in instances of the class being ordered by propertyX then by propertyY then by propertyZ when `Collection.sort(...)` is called on a `Collection<Boo>`.

Is a `Comparator` the way to go?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to compare objects by multiple fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/best-way-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Comment: I don't know why @sudocode deleted his answer. It pointed to [this excellent post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421322/how-do-i-sort-a-list-with-multiple-sort-parameters/1421458#1421458) which answers your question.

Comment: Answer by @Yishai in this post demonstrates elegant use of enum for custom sorting and grouped sorting (multiple arguments) utilizing comparator chaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You literally do what you suggest.

```
Comparator<Boo> booCmp = new Comparator<Boo>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Boo o1, Boo o2) {
        int cmp = o1.propertyX.compareTo(o2.propertyX);
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = o1.propertyY.compareTo(o2.propertyY);
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = o1.propertyZ.compareTo(o2.propertyZ);
        return cmp;
    }
};
```

Comment: Does this solution not break the rules for the Comparator.compare method? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if you don't implement `equals` similarly. Do you have something in mind?

Answer (score 0):

@sudocode gave a good answer but I think it is even too much for you. Just implement your custom comparator that compares `propertyX`, then `propertyY`. Use this comparator with `Collections.sort()` or `Arrays.sort()`