# Using enum to sort a list

Tags: java, sorting

I was looking around for a method to sort a list of objects based on just one of its multiple fields (and i ended up just asking the question myself) but in my research, I came across this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1421537/1549672

I'm fairly new to java and this may be why, but I don't quite understand this last method:

```
public static Comparator<Person> getComparator(final PersonComparator... multipleOptions) {
    return new Comparator<Person>() {
        public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
            for (PersonComparator option : multipleOptions) {
                int result = option.compare(o1, o2);
                if (result != 0) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    };
}
```

could someone please explain how it works...and what exactly it does?
Thanks!

Comment: I would step through the code in your debugger. This would allow you to see what each line does.

Comment: In this case it might actually be a bit difficult since the code execution is relatively complex. and the "compare" might not even get executed unless you write your own code to execute it.

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal() I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Is there some specific part about this code that you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getComparator` method will return comparator that will compare two `Person` objects based on comparators passed in its arguments. Each of `PersonComparator`s is designed to compare Person by one of Person class field, for example

- `PersonComparator.ID_SORT` will compare Person objects by `id` (0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < ...)
- `PersonComparator.NAME_SORT` will compare Person objects by name using natural (dictionary) order ("a" < "aa" < "ab" < "b").

If your Person class have more fields then you can add new comparator to enum `PersonComparator`.

Also order of PersonComparators passed to `getComparator` method is important.

For example, if you have Persons

```
Person p1 = new Person(1,"Jack");
Person p2 = new Person(2,"Jack");
Person p3 = new Person(2,"Adam");
```

and you will create comparator by

```
getComparator(PersonComparator.ID_SORT,PersonComparator.NAME_SORT)
```

it will sort person first by their `id`s and in case ids ware equal then it will sort them by their name

`(1,"Jack") (2,"Adam") (2,"Jack")`

Also comparator created by

```
getComparator(PersonComparator.NAME_SORT, PersonComparator.ID_SORT)
```

will firs compare names and only if names are equal it will compare ids of Persons, so you will get persons sorted this way

`(2,"Adam") (1,"Jack") (2,"Jack")`

Comment: Thank you! this was actually exactly what I was looking for! Just to clarify though, when you run getComparator, is it possible to use only 1 field? (ex. getComparator(PersonComparator.NAME_SORT) )?

Comment: Glad I could help. Also wanted to describe code but Markus Mikkolainen did it very good in his answer :)

Answer (score 4):

It will find the first comparator that will not return "equals" and return its value, otherwise it will return "equals".

Actually it will create a new Comparator to do this, by creating an anonymous class based on the Comparator-interface.

```
public static Comparator<Person> getComparator(
   final PersonComparator... multipleOptions) 
{        
    return new Comparator<Person>() { //create anonymous class 
        public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) { //which implements the only method 
                                                   //in Comparator
            for (PersonComparator option : multipleOptions) { //loop through given 
                                                              //comparators
                int result = option.compare(o1, o2);
                if (result != 0) {                         //return value of the first
                    return result;                         //which says "non-equal"
                }
            }
            return 0;//all said "equals" so we say "equals"
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this was very helpful in understanding what was going on!

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two person objects using [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29).

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer,
>   zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal
>   to, or greater than the second

Answer (score 0):

Basically this method receives a variable number of PersonComparator objects and then iterates through them to compare two person objects returning the first comparator that does not return   a match between two given person objects.

Answer (score 0):

You pass list of other comparators `final PersonComparator... multipleOptions` to method `getComparator`.

Your comparator use this PersonComparators in for loop and returns result if persons not equal due to current PersonComparator.

So, basically, this method returns Comparator, that return 0 if Persons are equal due to all passed comparators or return first non-matching int from the passed comparator `compareTo` method.