# Java: Priority Queue implementation iterable in proper order

Tags: java, iterator, priority-queue

I'm looking for some implementation of PQ in Java which allows iteration in PQ order - top element first, next one next etc. I tried using TreeSet (which implements NavigableSet) but it causes one problem. In my case:

- I'm using Comparator for my objects
- priority changes due to some external actions
- if priority changes I know for which object, but I don't know it's previous priority

As a result to the last point - I can't find my element in TreeSet when I would like to update its priority:/
Do you happen to know: smart way to obey this? or some implementation of PQ that is iterable in "good" way? or should I create some linked data structure that will match objects with their positions in tree ?

UPDATE:

- concurrency is not an issue
- object can't be removed from TreeSet because it's priority changed so Comparator will evaluate differently and object won't be found in this data structure. Inserting is not a problem.
- I can't use `compareTo` method as this priority is not proper way to compare those objects. That is why I need to use `Comparator`

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:

- create class `PrioritizedObject` which will be compared by priority and keep my object
- use map: my object -> `PrioritizedObject`
- keep `PrioritizedObject` in some `NavigableSet`

I would use this map to remove objects from `NavigableSet`. And of course update it with new elements if I add something.
Problem is that I will have to wrap iterator from this `NavigableSet` to get iterator returning my objects.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: so you have a bunch of objects stored in a queue, that are compared to each other by a Comparator that compares them based on their 'priority' field. While you iterate on that queue, some external objects might change the priority of some objects? Did I get it right?

Comment: yes. I know which object priority was changed and I would like to update it right away

Comment: it that case you need to lock your queue, update priority, then release the lock or you could use a ConcurrentLinkedQueue. You need to think about this queue in a multi-threaded environment

Comment: Concurrency is not an issue here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html it doesn't take priority into consideration nor any comparator

Comment: I do not understand the problem then. sorry

Comment: How many objects in the TreeSet? Can you just iterate through until you find the object?

Comment: I *really* would like to avoid this. This will happen quite often and amount of objects could be really big. For sure this could be done with some extra map and your own implementation of tree but I wonder whether there is some implemented solution or/and better way.

Comment: You shouldn't put things in a `Set` or `NavigableSet` if they can mutate such that `equals` and `compareTo` give different answers after a change - the `Set` implementation won't be able to obey its contract

Comment: You are right. Here I tried using `Comparator`, not `equals` or `compareTo`, but still true. That is why I'm asking for some way to work around this. I don't insist on using Set etc. This is something that I tried as first obvious idea ...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `ConcurrentSkipListSet` instead of `TreeSet` since it's thread-safe. If you know the object whose priority is changing, you can call `remove(objToChange)`, change its priority, then re-add it to the set.

Be very careful adding to a set any objects whose `equals`, `hashcode`, and `compareTo` methods depend on mutable fields.

Edit: I think any solution will end up looking like your `PrioritizedObject` which seems fine to me. If you want to iterate through your objects, use `Map.keySet`.

Comment: This is exactly what I have done but on different data structure - it won't work. Check update describing why

Answer (score 0):

If concurrency is not an issue all you need to do is to reorder the tree *right after* updating an element's priority. If I understood the problem right, this sketch should suit you.

Example element:

```
public class Element implements Comparable<Element> {

private final Integer id;
private Integer priority;

public Element(Integer id, Integer priority) {
    this.id = id;
    this.priority = priority;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Element{" + "id=" + id + ", priority=" + priority + '}';
}

public Integer getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public void setPriority(Integer priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Element o) {
    if (o == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    return priority.compareTo(o.priority);
}
}
```

The sketch:

```
public class Tree {

public static TreeSet<Element> priorityQueue = new TreeSet<Element>();

public static void dump(TreeSet<Element> in) {
    for (Element e : in) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

public static void updatePriority(Element e, int newPriority) {
    if (priorityQueue.remove(e)) {
        e.setPriority(newPriority);
        priorityQueue.add(e);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int id;
    Element lastElement = null;
    for (int i = 0;i < 10 ; i++) {
        id = (int)(Math.random()*1000);
        priorityQueue.add(lastElement = new Element(id, id));
    }
    dump(priorityQueue);
    updatePriority(lastElement, 0);
    System.out.println("updating "+lastElement+ " priority to 0");
    dump(priorityQueue);

}
}
```

You update the element by removing it from the [treeset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), setting the new priority and then reinserting it. The complexity of the update operation with this scenario is `2*O(log(n)) = O(log(n))`

UPDATE:

The best I could understand is: you have two criterias upon which you need to sort/index. When I had the same problem I used this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421322/how-do-i-sort-a-list-with-multiple-sort-parameters) but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940234/679982) is a very interesting approach that I strongly recommend reading.

Comment: Your code assumes that I know priority when I want to call `update`. If I knew that I wouldn't had issues with finding element in TreeMap ... BTW I don't agree with flame on `Comparators` ;) They enhance encapsulation and even DRY as you write it once and you can compose them.

Comment: But if you want to update a priority, you must know it prior too updating it. Now I rememebered you said it was "updated by exteternal actions". I give up, but will return to see the solution. I don't agree with it either, but I find his approach interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

> if priority changes I know for which object, but I don't know it's previous priority

You don't need to know its previous priority. All you have to do is remove it and re-insert it.