# Sorting an array of objects by more than one field

Tags: java, sorting

Say I have a array which holds 10 objects each with 3 values supposed to represent a league table

```
Team1 20 5
Team2 21 6
Team3 21 8
Team4 23 8
```

I want to sort by the first value (points) and then by the 2nd value (goal difference).

`Arrays.sort()` would work if I override the `compareto()` and write a piece of custom code.

Is there a easier way? By converting to a list etc.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creating a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is the correct way to solve this. Whether you then use [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,%20java.util.Comparator%29) or [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) is up to you.

I would suggest the former avoids a conversion to a list and is thus preferable.

I recommend you don't solve this by implementing `Comparable` in your object, as this sounds like a display issue and embedding a sort order in the object itself is probably not wise.

---

An example (untested) implementation might be:

```
public class ExampleComparator implements Comparator<YourObject> {

  public int compare(YourObject o1, YourObject o2) {
    if (o1 == null || o2 == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    if (o1.getValue1() != o2.getValue1()) {
      return Integer.compare(o1.getValue1(), o2.getValue1());
    }

    return Integer.compare(o1.getValue2(), o2.getValue2());
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried writing custom code in my compare to (which seems to work) I am keen to use a Comparator though. Are there any basic examples out there?

Comment: @DavidA See edits for an example implementation. See Google for a variety of real-world examples.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any `generic` in java, that would allow you to perform sort with multiple parameters. You have to implement your own sorting alogrithm or create your own `Comparator`. For more details, you should have a [look at this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421322/how-do-i-sort-a-list-with-multiple-sort-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut to this; convert your data to a class and override compareTo method.

```
Class Bean implements Comparable<Bean>{
  //attributes
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Object o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
 }
}
```

Then you can put you bean object in the list and do sorting..

```
List<Bean> list = new ArrayList<Bean>();
```