# Java comparable taking multiple parameters

Tags: java, enums, comparable

I want to sort on multiple fields and have found the answer : [How do I sort a list by different parameters at different timed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421322/how-do-i-sort-a-list-with-multiple-sort-parameters) which is what I was looking for.

I want to expand on it and pass a particular variable for specific enums. How can this be achieved? (the purpose of me passing a variable is so I can do a calculation and then sort based on that).

Comment: enums can have member variables like other classes. But I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. What do you mean with "** - variableName**" ?

Comment: Please add some more details. As it stands, your question is unclear

Comment: It would defeat the purpose of having an enum, wouldn't it?

Comment: I want to pass a integer to the enum, so when a particular enum gets called i can do further processing during the sort

Comment: If you need a parameterized comparator, then it can't be an enum, since you want to be able to create a specific comparator instance for every possible parameter value. Just create a ByIdWithParameterComparator class, taking a parameter as argument of its constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible (well, technically it's not impossible, but it would be a huge kludge with reflection, and a very bad idea). If you have a separate `Comparator` for all your different sort options (provided that there are only a handful, maybe 5-10 cases), you have a nice strongly typed system in place.

Besides, if the name is `ID_SORT`, why would you have it sort by anything besides the ID? It would be confusing to anyone using the code.

Comment: was just an example, i would do a different type of sort. just looking for a neat way of doing this

Comment: I think you're looking for a way to do that without having to write code. The resulting solution (with reflection) wouldn't be neat, even though it would be shorter.