# Sorting multiplecriteria using Comparator<> java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparable

I want to sort my object by many criteria but in different event/method.
example, there 2 options: 1 . Sort by name 2. Sort by Hit Point

```
public class MonsterArray implements Comparable<Monster>{
        ......
        public int compareTo(Monster m) {
         //what must i code here    
        }
}
```

can i use the compare to? or must using another sort.
please help me :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a list with multiple sort parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421322/how-do-i-sort-a-list-with-multiple-sort-parameters)

Comment: If you want to sort by different criteria, you implement different `Comparator`s (notice the difference to `Comparable`).

Comment: See http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/007-sort-arraylist-stream-of-objects-in-java8/#multiple-comparators