# How to sort with multiple sort parameters?

Tags: android, sorting, comparator

**Refering to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421322/how-do-i-sort-a-list-with-multiple-sort-parameters)**

Sadly I cannot comment because of low reputation but I have a question relating to this solution.
I want to sort ascending AND descending (on click), but keep an **empty string** (represents the second sort parameter) **always on top** of something written..

I want it like:

[image][image]

My code works only for ASCENDING, on descending the string is before the empty one..

```
SECOND_SORT {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1.equals("") && s2.equals("")) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (s1.equals("")) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (s2.equals("")) {
            return 1;
        }
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
```

This is the sort..

```
if (mSortingIdentifier == SortingIdentifier.DESC) {
            Collections.sort(list, Comparator.descending(Comparator.getComparator(Comparator.FIRST_SORT, Comparator.SECOND_SORT)));
        } else {
            Collections.sort(list, Comparator.ascending(Comparator.getComparator(Comparator.FIRST_SORT, Comparator.SECOND_SORT)));
        }
```

Comment: Why is B before B String in descending order?

Comment: Because thats the way I want it to be - emptystring always on top of strings :D
A/B and string/emptystring are two different variables of the object

Comment: Is it really a descending then? If you need your own customized comparator then you need to write your own with your own logic and you may not call it descending.

Comment: I thought I can do it with the if(s1.equals("")) { return -1; }
But I don't know why it doenst work

Comment: Why in the second table the B->Hi is before B->Hey? Does that should not be the other way?

Comment: Yes, you're right but actually this doesnt matter much for me.. its the comparisson between emptystring and somestring..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for me that works..
I just added another SECOND_SORT_DESC where I swap the return value.. in the adapter when I sort I check if its ASC or DESC and use the enum I want...

fyi:

```
SECOND_SORT_ASC {
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.equals("") && s2.equals("")) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (s1.equals("")) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (s2.equals("")) {
        return 1;
    }
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
},
SECOND_SORT_DESC {
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.equals("") && s2.equals("")) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (s1.equals("")) {
        return 1;
    }        // swapped these two
    if (s2.equals("")) {
        return -1;
    }
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
} // Here is where I differ between asc and desc
if (mSortingIdentifier == SortingIdentifier.DESC) {
        Collections.sort(list, Comparator.descending(Comparator.getComparator(Comparator.FIRST_SORT, Comparator.SECOND_SORT_DESC)));
    } else {
        Collections.sort(list, Comparator.ascending(Comparator.getComparator(Comparator.FIRST_SORT, Comparator.SECOND_SORT_ASC)));
    }
```