# Sort a List of objects by multiple fields

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a List of Java objects that I want to sort according to more than one field.

```
public class graduationCeremony {
    String campus;
    String faculty;
    String building;
}
```

Is it possible to use a `Comparator` or the `Comparable` interface to sort the list according to multiple fields? All the examples I have seen sort according to only one field. In other words, one can sort by 'campus' OR 'faculty' OR 'building'. I want to sort by 'campus', then 'faculty', then 'building' (as it exists in SQL: `ORDER BY campus, faculty, building`)

I think this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/best-way-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields), but I don't understand the accepted answer. Can someone expand or illustrate this answer?

Comment: The second answer to that question is a good illustration.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206073/sorting-a-collection-of-objects

Comment: @Moonbeam, the text of my question showed that I researched Collections and sorting, and I showed that I had already read other similar questions here on Stackoverflow. What makes you think I'm just fishing for code? Next time, please don't disregard Wheaton's Law.

Comment: @Moonbeam, sometimes you see to see code to understand a concept. Sure something like "My treeview flickers something awful!" "Try this" "Thanks!" doesnt help anyone learn, but that's why this is stackOverflow and not some forum.  See me after class.

Comment: "Can someone expand or illustrate this answer" no, not without you saying *specifically* what you do not understand about that question and its answers.

Comment: I use this one: Collections.sort( list, Comparator.comparing( (OBX obx) -> obx.getSequence() ).thenComparingInt( (OBX obx) -> obx.getId() ) );
you have compareInt, compare and many more to do group by sort.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Your Comparator would look like this:

```
public class GraduationCeremonyComparator implements Comparator<GraduationCeremony> {
    public int compare(GraduationCeremony o1, GraduationCeremony o2) {
        int value1 = o1.campus.compareTo(o2.campus);
        if (value1 == 0) {
            int value2 = o1.faculty.compareTo(o2.faculty);
            if (value2 == 0) {
                return o1.building.compareTo(o2.building);
            } else {
                return value2;
            }
        }
        return value1;
    }
}
```

Basically it continues comparing each successive attribute of your class whenever the compared attributes so far are equal (`== 0`).

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation helped the penny to drop. I have a clearer understanding of the usage of the compare() method now that I didn't have before.

Comment: don't forget your null checks. The line 'int value1 = o1.campus.compareTo(o2.campus);' will throw a NullPointerException if o1 is null

Answer (score 43):

Yes, you absolutely can do this. For example:

```
public class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person>
{
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2)
    {
        // Assume no nulls, and simple ordinal comparisons

        // First by campus - stop if this gives a result.
        int campusResult = p1.getCampus().compareTo(p2.getCampus());
        if (campusResult != 0)
        {
            return campusResult;
        }

        // Next by faculty
        int facultyResult = p1.getFaculty().compareTo(p2.getFaculty());
        if (facultyResult != 0)
        {
            return facultyResult;
        }

        // Finally by building
        return p1.getBuilding().compareTo(p2.getBuilding());
    }
}
```

Basically you're saying, "If I can tell which one comes first just by looking at the campus (before they come from different campuses, and the campus is the most important field) then I'll just return that result. Otherwise, I'll continue on to compare faculties. Again, stop if that's enough to tell them apart. Otherwise, (if the campus and faculty are the same for both people) just use the result of comparing them by building."

Comment: readability.. this should be the correct answer!

Answer (score 6):

If you know in advance which fields to use to make the comparison, then other people gave right answers.
What you may be interested in is to sort your collection in case you don't know at compile-time which criteria to apply.
Imagine you have a program dealing with cities:

```
    protected Set<City> cities;
    (...)
    Field temperatureField = City.class.getDeclaredField("temperature");
    Field numberOfInhabitantsField = City.class.getDeclaredField("numberOfInhabitants");
    Field rainfallField = City.class.getDeclaredField("rainfall");
    program.showCitiesSortBy(temperatureField, numberOfInhabitantsField, rainfallField);
    (...)
    public void showCitiesSortBy(Field... fields) {
        List<City> sortedCities = new ArrayList<City>(cities);
        Collections.sort(sortedCities, new City.CityMultiComparator(fields));
        for (City city : sortedCities) {
            System.out.println(city.toString());
        }
    }
```

where you can replace hard-coded field names by field names deduced from a user request in your program.

In this example, `City.CityMultiComparator<City>` is a static nested class of class `City` implementing `Comparator`:

```
    public static class CityMultiComparator implements Comparator<City> {
        protected List<Field> fields;

        public CityMultiComparator(Field... orderedFields) {
            fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
            for (Field field : orderedFields) {
                fields.add(field);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(City cityA, City cityB) {
            Integer score = 0;
            Boolean continueComparison = true;
            Iterator itFields = fields.iterator();

            while (itFields.hasNext() && continueComparison) {
                Field field = itFields.next();
                Integer currentScore = 0;
                if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("temperature")) {
                    currentScore = cityA.getTemperature().compareTo(cityB.getTemperature());
                } else if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("numberOfInhabitants")) {
                    currentScore = cityA.getNumberOfInhabitants().compareTo(cityB.getNumberOfInhabitants());
                } else if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("rainfall")) {
                    currentScore = cityA.getRainfall().compareTo(cityB.getRainfall());
                }
                if (currentScore != 0) {
                    continueComparison = false;
                }
                score = currentScore;
            }

            return score;
        }
    }
```

You may want to add an extra layer of precision, to specify, for each field, whether sorting should be ascendant or descendant. I guess a solution is to replace `Field` objects by objects of a class you could call *`SortedField`*, containing a `Field` object, plus another field meaning *ascendant* or *descendant*.

Comment: best answer that i was looking for from my side +10

Answer (score 2):

Hope this Helps:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;

class Person implements Comparable {
  String firstName, lastName;

  public Person(String f, String l) {
    this.firstName = f;
    this.lastName = l;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "[ firstname=" + firstName + ",lastname=" + lastName + "]";
  }

  public int compareTo(Object obj) {
    Person emp = (Person) obj;
    int deptComp = firstName.compareTo(emp.getFirstName());

    return ((deptComp == 0) ? lastName.compareTo(emp.getLastName()) : deptComp);
  }

  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Person)) {
      return false;
    }
    Person emp = (Person) obj;
    return firstName.equals(emp.getFirstName()) && lastName.equals(emp.getLastName());
  }
}

class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
  public int compare(Person emp1, Person emp2) {
    int nameComp = emp1.getLastName().compareTo(emp2.getLastName());
    return ((nameComp == 0) ? emp1.getFirstName().compareTo(emp2.getFirstName()) : nameComp);
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList<Person> names = new ArrayList<Person>();
    names.add(new Person("E", "T"));
    names.add(new Person("A", "G"));
    names.add(new Person("B", "H"));
    names.add(new Person("C", "J"));

    Iterator iter1 = names.iterator();
    while (iter1.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(iter1.next());
    }
    Collections.sort(names, new PersonComparator());
    Iterator iter2 = names.iterator();
    while (iter2.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(iter2.next());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have your class inherit from [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

then implement the [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29/Comparable.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29) method the way you like.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own compareTo() method that has the Java code needed to perform the comparison.

If we wanted for example to compare two public fields, campus, then faculty, we might do something like:

```
int compareTo(GraduationCeremony gc)
{
    int c = this.campus.compareTo(gc.campus);

    if( c != 0 )
    {
        //sort by campus if we can
        return c;
    }
    else
    {
        //campus equal, so sort by faculty
        return this.faculty.compareTo(gc.faculty);
    }
}
```

This is simplified but hopefully gives you an idea. Consult the Comparable and Comparator docs for more info.