# order arraylist based on values

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

Here is the actual scenario. Have a VO

```
Name Usagecount  returncount number
A   0       0       123
B   1       1           234
C   0       2       345
D   2       3       546
```

First it should sort based on usage count, descending order. If same usage count found then it should sort based on return code in ascending order.If same return count is found then it should sorted with number in ascending order.
When i tried this below code snippet

```
public class SomeComparator implements Comparator<SomeVO> {
        @Override
        public int compare(SomeVO o1, SomeVO o2) {
            int value1 = o2.getUsageCount().compareTo(o1.getUsageCount());
            if (value1 == 0) {
                int value2 = o1.getNumberofReturns().compareTo(o2.getNumberofReturns());
                if (value2 == 0) {
                    return o1.getNumber().compareTo(o2.getNumber());
                } else {
                    return value2;
                }
            }
            return value1;
        }
    }
```

I get output D,B,C, but i am expecting it as D,B,A,C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a List of objects by multiple fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850611/sort-a-list-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 4):

No. You should be able to implement all sorting logic in your `Comparator` (or `Comparable`) implementation.

For instance (pseudo-code):

- Compare by color (lexicographically apparently, i.e. your example puts "Black" before "black")
- If equal, compare by seats

Your `Collections.sort` invocation will then perform the appropriate sort based on your logic within `compare` or `compareTo`.

Comment: i have edited my question with actual scenario, could you please help? @Mena