# How to rearrange objects in arraylist based on card type

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, sorting

I have a scenario where I have to rearrange the elements of bank name in a particular order.
This list can be in any order [Wellsfargo, Bank of America, Chase, Citi, American Express] and may not have one or more of the banks in the list.
I'm trying to think of logic to rearrange to only this order.
[Chase, Citi, Bank Of America, Wellsfargo, American Express]

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: So, is "card type" order, just alphabetical order, right?  Have you looked at the Collections Java framework?  https://dev.java/learn/the-collections-framework/

Comment: Not the alphabetical order. Need it custom ordered based on the type of bank issued cards

Comment: Do you already know [`List.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator))? Try to come up with an appropriate `Comparator`.

Comment: Yes, I know. I thought of the comparator but thinking, it might not work. I need to check multiple fields to put the banks in that order. Can you show me an example of how to implement Comparator with multiple layers

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850611/sort-a-list-of-objects-by-multiple-fields, for using a custom comparator

Answer (score 1):

As noticed in the comments, you can `sort` with a custom `Comparator` comparing element's `indexOf` a `List` with the desired order:

```
private static final List<String> ORDER_LIST = List.of("Chase", "Citi", "Bank Of America", "Wellsfargo", "American Express");

public static List<String> sort(String... names) {
    return Stream.of(names)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(ORDER_LIST::indexOf))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then you can do:

```
List<String> names = sort("American Express", "Citi", "Chase");
    
System.out.println(names);
```

Output:

```
[Chase, Citi, American Express]
```

Comment: I need to look inside the object for more variables, like if card is Master/Visa for Citi, Bank Of America. And if its a default card.

Comment: You should create a new question with a detailed explanation of what you want to achieve and share the code with what you have tried so far