# Sorting the List

Tags: java, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting a collection of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206073/sorting-a-collection-of-objects)

How to sort the list in java

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(13);
list.add(8);
list.add(6);
list.add(4);
list.add(3);
```

i want to sort the list. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use:

```
 Collections.sort(list);
```

if you want to sort in reverse order you have to implement the Comparator interface

```
public class MyIntComparable implements Comparator<Integer>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return (o1>o2 ? -1 : (o1==o2 ? 0 : 1));
    }
}
```

and in your code use:

```
Collections.sort(list, new MyIntComparable());
```

Comment: The objects have to implement Comparable in all cases!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Collections.sort(list), but note that your list must be made of objects that implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) to use this!
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/coll_sortlist.html) should help. It's an example for String list, but it should be working for integers too. Must say, I didn't try it myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(13);
list.add(8);
list.add(6);
list.add(4);
list.add(3);
Collections.sort(list);
```