# Java: Sorting an ArrayList<MyObject> based on a MyObject variable

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting a collection of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206073/sorting-a-collection-of-objects)
>   [Sorting an ArrayList of Contacts based on name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts-based-on-name)

A quick question for you:

I've got an `ArrayList<MyObject>` filled with `MyObject` objects. I would like them to be sorted based on an integer variable of `MyObject`.

Is there a ready way to implement this or will I have to write a quicksort/mergesort myself?

Thank you for your time,
Dimitris

Comment: ok post the structure of your 'myobject'

Comment: @Arpit It's a basic `class MyObject{ private int num; /*constructor, setter and getter for num here*/ }` , friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the `Collections.sort()` libraries and pass in your collections (`ArrayList`) and a specifically designed `Comperator` for your objects.

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html[enter link description here][1]
```

Comment: Thank you, friend. It was as simple as I thought.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement Comparable interface and override the compareTo.
Following example I have assumed that there is a member variable 'name' on which you will be comparing the objects.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject>{
private String name;
private int id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public MyObject(String name, int id) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}
@Override
public int compareTo(MyObject o) {
    return name.compareTo(o.getName());
}   
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name+"\t"+id+"\n";
}
}

         public class Test {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
     list.add(new MyObject("John", 10));
     list.add(new MyObject("Mark", 11));
     list.add(new MyObject("Steve", 9));
     Collections.sort(list);
     System.out.println("Sorted list is :"+list);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at Comparators, they let you define the sort order whatever way you want. Here's the doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.sort(...)` You must only implement a `Comparator` for your `MyObject` or make it `Comparable`.