# Sorting Arraylist of objects based on array of doubles?

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

Hi I'm very new to this so I have no idea how to figure this out after thinking for couple days, I have a question regarding the sorting of Objects inside of an ArrayList. I have a single ArrayList that contains Objects. Each Object has a double "distance". I want to sort my Objects within the ArrayList based on the smallest distance.

I been struggling on this one for a while now since I suck with sorting :( If anyone can help me out I would appreciate it, and let me know if I'm being to vague, not sure how to explain it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a collection of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206073/sorting-a-collection-of-objects). See also: [Sorting an ArrayList of Contacts based on name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts-based-on-name?lq=1) and [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property).

Comment: Typing in the title gives you numerous relevant "questions that may already have your answer". OP did not put in too much effort here...

Comment: I did search but couldn't understand most of them, I'm very new to programming :(

Comment: @Riven Then unfortunately you probably did not understand the answer you chose, but it just works. Please take a look at the other answers so you understand why. Becoming better at programming is not just about having code that works.

Comment: @ Zong Zheng Li I understood the answer I chose, what I meant was I didn't understand the Collections class when I was searching for a solution to this, but now I mostly understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's good to provide accessors for the `distance` property in the class you have.

Then, in order to sort the list based on the `distance` field of the objects within, you can use an *anonymous implementation* of the `Comparator` interface.

```
List<MyObject> list = ...;
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        if (o1.getDistance() == o2.getDistance()) { 
             return 0;
        } else { 
           return o1.getDistance() > o2.getDistance() ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Omg yes! THANK YOU! I been trying to figure this out for a while it's finally working smoothly :D

Answer (score 2):

I think a slight improvement on the previous answer is box into a Double then use compareTo

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return new Double(o1.getDistance()).compareTo(o2.getDistance());
    }
});
```

If you want to sort largest first then change to

```
return new Double(o2.getDistance()).compareTo(o1.getDistance());
```