# Sort names in Java ArrayList?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I have an arraylist containing names, ages, salaries, etc.

I want to sort the list by name.

The following is what I have in my class:

```
//Sort by Name
public ArrayList<Employee> sortByName()
{
  Collections.sort(employees);
  return employees;
}
```

I have a comparator (which I'm not sure is even being used) here:

```
import java.util.*;

public class EmployeeNameComparator implements Comparator<Employee>
{
   ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

   //METHODS
   //Name Compare
   public int compare(Employee object1, Employee object2)
   {
      return object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName());
   }
}
```

And here are the relevant parts of the tester I've made:

```
CompanyDataBase database = new CompanyDataBase();

  database.addEmployee(new Employee("John James", 34, 45000));
  database.addEmployee(new Employee("Josie Gibson", 19, 19000));
  database.addEmployee(new Employee("Luke Marsden", 28, 30000));
  database.addEmployee(new Manager("Aaron Morgan", 28, 44000, 5500));

  System.out.println("\n\nSORT BY NAME");
  //Collections.sort(database.getEmployees());
  database.sortByName();

  for(Employee currEmployee: database.getEmployees())
  {
     System.out.println(currEmployee.getDescription());
  }
```

I've tried this loads of ways but nothing seems to be working, does anyone know where I'm going wrong or how to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: See the overloaded `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a collection of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206073/sorting-a-collection-of-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort objects by name using a comparator the second parameter required.

```
Collections.sort(employees, new EmployeeNameComparator());
```

See the [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/) of using a custom comparator.

Answer (score 3):

use the method [`Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort a collection with a given comparator

```
 Collections.sort(employees, new EmployeeNameComparator());
```