# Sort Photo ArrayList alphabetically based on Photo attributes

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have already searched through the site, finding many resources, none of which answer this question. Consider reading before down voting or marking as duplicate.

I CANNOT USE A COMPARATOR INTERFACE OR `.sort()`

I have an ArrayList of Photo objects named "photoAlbum" like this `ArrayList<Photo> photoAlbum = new ArrayList<Photo>();` where each Photo object contains a String attribute named `photographerName`.  I need to to sort the Photo objects alphabetically with the `photographerName` attribute. I understand that I can use bubble sort or exchange sort, but how can I actually sort the Photo objects themselves inside the `photoAlbum` ArrayList based off of each photos `photographerName` attribute?

Just tips or generic example would be unbelievably appreciated.

PS I am not allowed to use a `Comparator` interface or the `.sort` method.

Comment: How hard did you try to search for duplicates yourself?  I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206073/sorting-a-collection-of-objects, and yes, I did read both your question and that one.

Comment: I am not allowed to implement a comparator interface.

Comment: Not your fault, but I despair of professors who set an assignment, then forbid the students from doing the assignment the correct way.

Comment: They are wanting us to understand the fundamentals of using the sorting algorithms. I agree though..  Why does this always happen to me.. please remove the duplicate mark so that people actually view my question. Please.

Comment: I guess that's the difference between learning computer programming and learning computer science.  I got my first programming job in 1990, and I don't understand the fundamentals of the sorting algorithms.  Every language you're ever likely to program in has some equivalent to `Collections.sort` and it's only in a very limited set of applications that it's wrong to just use it.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Collections.sort(your array list object, new comparator());

public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Your Array List> {
        @Override
        public int compare(ClassObj o1, ClassObj o2) {
            return String.valueOf(o1.getName()).compareTo(String.valueOf(o2.getName()));
        }
    }
```

or try this logic :

```
  import java.util.*;

    public class BubbleSort {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    String l[]={"ABCD" , "XYZ" , "DEF" , "PQR"};
    BubbleSort(l);
    for(int i=0; i<l.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(l[i]);
    }
  }

 private static void BubbleSort(String[] array) {
    String t;
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<array.length-1-i; j++) {
        if(array[j].compareTo(array[j+1])>0) {
            t= array[j];
            array[j] = array[j+1];
            array[j+1] = t;
        }
    }
    }
}
   }
```

Comment: cough: Comparator<ClassObj>

Comment: I am looking for the actual sort algorithm, I cannot use `.sort()`. This is for a college course.

Comment: check edited answer pass your arraylist object in place of array.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method

```
public static comparePhotos(Photo a, Photo b) {
    return a.photographerName.compareTo(b.photographerName);
}
```

Then anywhere in your sorting algorithm where you want to compare Photos:

instead of doing this:

```
if(photo1 < photo2) //this wouldn't work
```

you do:

```
if(comparePhotos(photo1, photo2) < 1)
```

comparePhotos will return a **negative** if `photo1.photographerName` is less than `photo2.photographerName`, **0** if they're **equal**, and a **positive** if `photo1.photographerName` is greater than `photo2.photographerName`

Comment: LOL.  How to have a Comparator without having a Comparator.  +1 for making me smile.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. Photo class will implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and you will implement `compareTo` method in Photo class. Then you just need to call `Collections.sort(photoAlbum);`
2. You will implement your own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and call `Collections.sort(photoAlbum, comparator);`. In this way, you don't need to modify Photo class.

Edit: If you can't use this, just implement your favorite sort algorithm. Or have a look into Java implementation of sort function.