# How can I change the value of an enum variable in a different class?

Tags: java, sorting, enums

I am currently working on a project that asks me to sort a collection of songs.
I am using the solution presented in this question to accomplish this, while modifying it slightly:[Sorting a collection of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206073/sorting-a-collection-of-objects)

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SongComparator implements Comparator<Song> {
    public enum Order {
        YEAR_SORT, RANK_SORT, ARTIST_SORT, TITLE_SORT
    }

    public Order sortingBy;

    @Override
    public int compare(Song song1, Song song2) {
        switch (sortingBy) {
        case YEAR_SORT:
            return Integer.compare(song1.year, song2.year);
        case RANK_SORT:
            return Integer.compare(song1.rank, song2.rank);
        case ARTIST_SORT:
            return song1.artist.compareTo(song2.artist);
        case TITLE_SORT:
            return song1.title.compareTo(song2.title);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Practically unreachable code, can't be thrown");
    }

    public void setSortingBy(Order sortBy) {
            this.sortingBy = sortingBy;
    } 
}
```

Example sort method:

```
public void sortTitle() {
    SongComparator comparator = new SongComparator();
    SongComparator.Order sortingBy = SongComparator.Order.TITLE_SORT;

      Collections.sort(songs2, comparator);
    }
```

I want to be able to change the `sortingBy` variable when each respective `sortField` method is run, so that way it will run the right compare method. However, the way that I'm defining it in the method is just making a new `sortingBy` variable without changing the one in the `SongComparator` class at all.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You had better make the inner enum implement `Comparator<Song>`; it would be much cleaner

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally submitted the question without fulling typing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set the `sortingBy` field of the comparator:

```
comparator.setSortingBy(sortingBy);
Collections.sort(songs2, comparator);
```

You'd better pass this value as a constructor parameter, to make sure the comparator is always in a valid state, and that you don't reproduce the bug:

```
SongComparator comparator = new SongComparator(SongComparator.Order.TITLE_SORT);
Collections.sort(songs2, comparator);
```

The `sortingBy` field shouldn't be public, by the way, and there should be no setter for the `sortingBy` field.

To make the class easier and friendlier to use, I would create factory methods:

```
public static SongComparator byTitle() {
    return new SongComparator(SongComparator.Order.TITLE_SORT);
}

public static SongComparator byYear() {
    return new SongComparator(SongComparator.Order.YEAR_SORT);
}
...
```

So that the code in the callers become:

```
Collections.sort(songs2, SongComparator.byTitle());
```

Note that with Java 8, this comparator class becomes unnecessary. You can simply use

```
Collections.sort(songs2, Comparator.comparing(Song::getTitle));
```