# Java sort ArrayList as an class structure

Tags: java

in this function my sort doesnot work correctly. my lastID is string

```
private void addDataToList(String LastID, String SmsBody) {
    List<ReceivedItemStructure> receivedItemStructures = 
      new ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure>();
    ReceivedItemStructure rS = new ReceivedItemStructure();

    rS.setmLastID(LastID);
    rS.setmSmsBody(SmsBody);
    items.add(rS);

    Collections.sort(receivedItemStructures, new Comparator<ReceivedItemStructure>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ReceivedItemStructure  rs1, ReceivedItemStructure  rs2)
        {
            if( rs1.getmLastID().equals(rs2.getmLastID()) )
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    });
    adapter.setRow(items);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

ReceivedItemStructure class:

```
public class ReceivedItemStructure {
    public String mLastID;
    public String mSmsBody;

    public ReceivedItemStructure(String vLastID, String vSmsBody) {
        mLastID  = vLastID;
        mSmsBody = vSmsBody;
    }

    public ReceivedItemStructure() {}

    public String getmLastID() {
        return mLastID;
    }

    public void setmLastID(String LastID) {
        mLastID = LastID;
    }
```

**POST UPDATE catLog Result :**

```
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30390335
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30390100
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30389996
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30374135
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30374099
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30374093
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30374084
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30374062
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30373780
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30373756
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30390748
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30390755
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30391045
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30391076
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30391095
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30395978
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30395972
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30395990
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30396009
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30396045
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30396250
10-11 14:27:51.860    4658-4658/ir.tsms E/LastID:﹕ 30396259
```

`getmLastID` return string value and `return  rs1.getmLastID().compareTo(rs2.getmLastID());` not working. whats my code problem and how to resolve that?

Comment: What does `getmLastID()` return?

Comment: @Mureinik i say in topic thats as an string and return String

Comment: So why isn't `return  rs1.getmLastID().compareTo(rs2.getmLastID())` not working? Please share the input, the output you're getting and why you think the result is wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a collection of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206073/sorting-a-collection-of-objects)

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [`Comparator.compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) method (emphasis mine):

> Compares its two arguments for order. **Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is [respectively] less than, equal to, or greater than the second.**

Is your `compare` function following the contract properly?

---

Unless the ID can be longer than 18 digits, I suggest that you store the ID as `long` type. Implementing the `compare` function will be as simple as:

```
public int compare(ReceivedItemStructure  rs1, ReceivedItemStructure  rs2)
{
    return rs1.getmLastID() - rs2.getmLastID();
}
```

If you still want to store your ID as String type:

```
public int compare(ReceivedItemStructure  rs1, ReceivedItemStructure  rs2)
{
    if (rs1.getmLastID().length() == rs2.getmLastID().length()) {
        return rs1.getmLastID().compareTo(rs2.getmLastID());
    } else {
        return rs1.getmLastID().length() - rs2.getmLastID().length();
    }
}
```

Using `return rs1.getmLastID().compareTo(rs2.getmLastID());` directly will not work correctly when you compare `35` and `345`, since String compares by lexicographic order and it does not correspond to the ordering of natural number when the numbers don't have the same number of digits.

Comment: i return 1 or 0 with `if` method. thats not correct?

Comment: @andbee: Read the bold text. Is the ordering imposed by your code correct according to your expected result?

Comment: @andbee: We don't know what your `ID` format is. We don't know if you want sort by String comparison or numeric comparison. So the best I can tell you is that: check your requirement, and write your function so that it follows the contract of `Comparator.compare`

Comment: post updated. i'm paste result from logCat for LastID