# ArrayList not printing as expected

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a simple `ArrayList` and it doesn't seem to print the way I want it to. I have a class name `Person` which is as follows:

```
public class Person {
public String Name;
public String Ni;
public String Dob;

public Person(String name, String ni, String dob){
    this.Name = name;
    this.Ni = ni;
    this.Dob = dob;
}

public String toString()
{
    return this.Name + " " + this.Ni + " " + this.Dob;
}
}
```

And then to print the list I simply do

```
 public static void main(String []args){
 
    ArrayList<Person> myList = new ArrayList();
    
    myList.add(new Person("John Smith","123456789","01/01/1990"));
    myList.add(new Person("John Test","9876543211","15/05/1984"));
    myList.add(new Person("Some Person","147852369","15/05/1991"));
    
    for(Person person : myList)
    {
        System.out.println(person);
    }
    
 }
```

It prints the list as expected however I'm trying to descend by `Dob` but I can't seem to work out how to achieve this. I've tried `Collections.sort` after implementing my `Person` class but still have the same issue.

Actual Result:

> John Smith 123456789 01/01/1990
>
> John Test 9876543211 15/05/1984
>
> Some Person 147852369 15/05/1991

Desired Reasult:

> John Test 9876543211 15/05/1984
>
> John Smith 123456789 01/01/1990
>
> Some Person 147852369 15/05/1991

Would highly appreciate it if someone can help me on this issue.

Comment: You haven't shown any code doing any sorting at all - so of course it's not sorted. Please show the code you've tried in order to sort it...

Comment: You need to sort your list.

Comment: `Collections.sort`  is the way to go, but you must properly implement `Comparable<Person>` in `Person` or create a `Comparator<Person>`. Show us what you have done about that.

Comment: You'll need to show us how you tried sorting. Include the call to Collections.sort, and also the custom comparator you used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a collection of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206073/sorting-a-collection-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to **sort** by date of birth, right (not "descend")? You need to make your class implement `Comparable` interface to be able to sort (or pass an implementation of a `Comparator` to sort method).

Option 1:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    public String Name;
    public String Ni;
    public String Dob;

    public Person(String name, String ni, String dob){
        this.Name = name;
        this.Ni = ni;
        this.Dob = dob;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person person) {
        return Dob.compareTo(person.getDob()); // you really want to compare by who is younger here right? whatever it is, put it here instead of String compare
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return Dob;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.Name + " " + this.Ni + " " + this.Dob;
    }
}
```

Then you can invoke `Collections.sort(myList);`

Alternative, use `Collections.sort(myList, comparator)` and provide a comparator there. An example with anonymous inner class implementation:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return 0; // do your comparson here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this I completely understand now. I wasn't camparing them properply

Answer (score 1):

```
myList.add(new Person("John Test","9876543211","15/05/1984"));
myList.add(new Person("John Smith","123456789","01/01/1990"));
myList.add(new Person("Some Person","147852369","15/05/1991"));
```

add like this because arrayList use index to get data. 0 is John Smith because you added it first to list . when iterating 0 gets printed first in the for loop

Comment: if you want  sorted data use sortedSet but duplication is not possible in set

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PersonAgeComparator implements Comparator<Person>
{
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2)
    {
        return p1.getAge() - p2.getAge();
    }
}
```

To invoke the sort you would use:

```
Collections.sort(people, new PersonAgeComparator());
```

You will find below link usefull.

https://himanshugpt.wordpress.com/2010/09/10/sorting-list-in-java/

Hope this helps :)