# Sorting a list depending of the value of a key

Tags: java

I have a list that contains names of users.

```
List<String> members = new ArrayList<>();
```

And I store the users and their points like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> membersAndPoints = new HashMap<>();

for(String member : members) {
    membersAndPoints.put(member, Utils.getPoints(member));
}
```

Note that the points are not unique, if more than one user has the same points, they have to be in a similar position.
Then I want to sort the members depending on the values of the map, that's what I dont know how to do.
If a member has 1000 points, and no one else has more than that, that member would be in the position 0 of the ranking, and so on.

```
List<String> ranking = new ArrayList<>();
```

Looking at the respones I got I did this, but I'm not sure if its that what I want or not.

```
Collections.sort(clans, new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                        return Integer.valueOf(Utils.getPoints(o1)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(Utils.getPoints(o2)));
                    }
                });
```

Edit:
I did this, and it works:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
            {
                add("Example1");
                add("Example2");
                add("Example3");
                add("Example4");
                add("Example5");
            }
        };
        list.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                return getFor(s2).compareTo(getFor(s1));
            }
        });
        for(String s : list) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s : %s", s, getFor(s)));
        }
    }

    public static Integer getFor(String s) {
        switch (s) {
        case "Example1":
            return 29;
        case "Example2":
            return 94;
        case "Example3":
            return 67;
        case "Example4":
            return 34;
        case "Example5":
            return 94;
        default:
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if 2 members have same points ?

Comment: In the duplicate, see in particular: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23846961/829571

Comment: The duplicate is not well-chosen. I would have picked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206073/sorting-a-collection-of-objects

Comment: I cant use Java 8 streams, I need java 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use comparators. Where you should override **`compareTo`** method. There you should compare each entry set based on their value.

or

Alternatively you can use **`Sorted Maps`** also with your custom comparator. It will keep your entry set sorted as per comparators

Comment: Correct but a bit short

Comment: This should rather be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Dici yes, actually, I was editing at the same time. I could also provide code snippets but I also wanted the person to know about comparator and compareTo method by own.

Comment: @SacJn `LinkedHashMap` is not *sorted*, it is *ordered*. You probably meant `TreeMap`

Comment: @Dici based on the comparator I provide to my map reference at the time of creating it, it sorts each new entry to it

Comment: @SacJn No, look at the doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Comment: @Dici sorry, Just mixed up with sortedMaps with LinkedHashMap, though they actually maintain insertion order only while iterating over them .

Comment: @SacJn yes that's what I said. It is ordered, not sorted