# Java: Effizient List Sorting

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I have a `List` containing a variable amount of objects (often more than 1000). These objects have certain attributes, for example price and distance (both int).

Now I want to be able to sort the `List` from cheapest to most expensive **OR** from closest to furthest away, but I don't know how to implement this. I already tried making my object implement `Comparable`, but this only lets me sort by one of the properties... How can I sort based on different properties?

Comment: The only thing wrong we can tell so far is that you haven't posted your code.

Comment: Related/similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206073/sorting-a-collection-of-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just make use the `Collections.sort(...)` and implement custom comparators for each type of sorting, for example, by price.

```
Collections.sort(effizientObjects, new Comparator<EffizientObject>() {
    @Override public int compare(EffizientObject p1, EffizientObject p2) {
        return p1.price- p2.price;
    }
});
```

Comment: NB: you should use [`Integer.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) (or `Double.compare`, or whichever type) to compare numeric values, rather than subtracting, to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 5):

Create two different implementations of [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) - one that compares price, and one that compares distance.

Then you can use [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) to sort the list using whichever sorting strategy you want.