# Sort Nodes by an attribute in Graphstream

Tags: java, collections, graphstream

I am trying to sort a collection of nodes of Graphstream by an attribute. I am not sure how this can be done.

```
Collection <Node> function (Graph graph){
    BetweennessCentrality bcb = new BetweennessCentrality();
    bcb.init(graph);
    bcb.compute();

    System.out.println("A=" + graph.getNode("A").getAttribute("Cb")); // prints the calculated measure

    return graph.getNodeSet();
}
```

The function returns the set of nodes with their attributes but not sorted.

How can I sort the collection of nodes by the attribute calculated?

Comment: The http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206073/sorting-a-collection-of-objects doesn't answer my question.

Comment: If you're not trying to sort a collection like your question asked, what are you trying to do?

Comment: you're right, it's the same problem in the end.