# Sort arraylist to display items by date

Tags: android, arraylist

i am developing a news app which it composed of:

Title,description,time,date

The date format is as : 12/7/2017

When i am adding multiples news they are showed randomly on the recyclerview.

What is the best way to use Comparator object to sort the arraylist by date so when i add a news it must show up in recyclerview top.

This is my working code :

```
 JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            post_array2.clear();
            Simplenews_data p;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                int id_simplenews = jsonObject.getInt("id_simplenews");
                String name_simplenews = jsonObject.getString("name_simplenews");
                String image_simplenews = jsonObject.getString("image_simplenews");
                String desc_simplenews = jsonObject.getString("desc_simplenews");
                String time_simplenews = jsonObject.getString("time_simplenews");
                String date_simplenews = jsonObject.getString("date_simplenews");



                p = new Simplenews_data();
                p.setId_simplenews(id_simplenews);
                p.setName_simplenews(name_simplenews);
                p.setImage_simplenews(image_simplenews);
                p.setDesc_simplenews(desc_simplenews);
                p.setTime_simplenews(time_simplenews);
                p.setDate_simplenews(date_simplenews);

                post_array2.add(p);
```

I have searched and found this code that works for other issue if u have to compare two integers :

```
Collections.sort(post_array, new Comparator<Standings_data>(){
                public int compare(Standings_data s1, Standings_data s2) {
                    return s1.getPts().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getPts());
                }
            });
```

But really i don 't have any idea how to sort it by this date format so when a news come it shows in top of recyclerview not randomly.

This a simple screenshot of the current situation:

[image]

Comment: Create a Date object out of the string, using a SimpleDateFormat.parse() and then use date's compareTo method.

Comment: Would you please post some code

Comment: I would not. You could just google for what I said and find the answer easily. But you'd rather for someone to do everything for you. For that, there are sites as well, but you need to pay usually. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks i found the solution but no need to downvote my question ..

Answer (score 1):

Extract year, month and day by spliting your String :

`String[] parts = date.split("/");`

Convert into Integers then compare year, month and day.

Should works.

(Vucko answer is better if you can parse with SimpleDateFormat)

Comment: If i did that how can i make the recyclerview shows the items by the compared date ?

Comment: Well, the RecyclerView display the items in the same order than the ArrayList. So sort the ArrayList before displaying it or call the `notifyDataSetChanged` function once the ArrayList sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the `String`s to `Date`s like Vucko recommends, or you could convert the dates to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format and sort them alphabetically.

ISO 8601 looks like YYYY-mm-dd so alphabetically sorting these as strings will sort by year, month, then day, which effectively sorts the strings chronologically.

`isodate = date.subString(5) + date.subString(0,2) + date.substring(3,4)`
This will leave you with an edge case of dates with 1 or 2 numbers (7 vs 17) but that should hopefully encourage you to use a better date format. You can find out how to sort the `ArrayList` here [Sorting a collection of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206073/sorting-a-collection-of-objects)